# FullSimplify ratio of two gamma functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following input

```
m = 2;
Gamma[n + m]/Gamma[n + 1];
FullSimplify[%]
```

It gives me

```
1+n
```

For `m=3`, it gives me

```
(1 + n) (2 + n)
```

For `m=4`, it gives me

```
(1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n)
```

For `m=5`, it gives me

```
Gamma[5 + n]/Gamma[1 + n]
```

I would like to have expression like `(1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (4+n),` how should I do to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) for this.

```
gammaFRatio[m_] := FunctionExpand[Gamma[n + m]/Gamma[n + 1]]
```

Example:

```
gammaFRatio[10]
```

> ```
> (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (4 + n) (5 + n) (6 + n) (7 + n) (8 + n) (9 + n)
> ```